# Script to track Database change

Tags: postgresql

I need to track any changes of data in postgresql database. Is there any option in database or any script to view those data and DML as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I have no clue.  But I do have some different suggestions:

- Log /all/ queries and grep for those involving update, delete, insert, alter table etc.  Caveats: may cause performance problems if there are lots of queries and the log is on the same RAID as data and/or WAL.  Not sure if it's easy to make some regexp that is 100% certain to catch all modifying statements.  May be difficult to catch rollbacks etc.  To log everything, add this to the configuration file: `log_min_duration_statement = 0`.  Have a look that the other log_* configuration variables are sane as well.
- The rules/trigger approach (as hinted by other user) - I believe it involves writing up rules for each and every table - but it's of course doable (and should be possible to create the rules through some external script if you have a lot of tables).  You may also look a bit into how slony works - slony is a trigger-based replication system, should be possible to use it to catch all the changes in the DB.
- All changes to the database ends up in the WAL-file, maybe it's theoretically possible to extract something out from the WAL, but I suspect that's not practical unless you're already a skilled postgres hacker ... and if you're a skilled postgres hacker, you probably wouldn't ask this question in the first place ;-) (eventually, the WALs may be used to see the rate of changes in the data and spot times of the day when there are more updates than otherwise etc.  They may also be used for replication and roll-forward from a binary backup)

Comment: Log file is showing:   unexpected EOF on client connection
2012-06-14 12:09:34 BDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: That's not a query.  If that's all you can see in the log file, then you definitively didn't succeed to turn on query logging.

Answer (score 0):

Between setting log_statement='all' in the postgresql.conf, you can also use tablelog to capture old data.